# Can we copy files from S3 to multiple Azure blobs using Azcopy?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am working on Azcopy data movement from S3 storage to Azure blob. Now I need to copy data from S3 storage (one source) to two different Azure blobs(multiple destinations).

I used Azcopy with one source and one destination, It is working fine. But in case of one source and multiple destination, Can we do that in single command or we do It by running separate Azcopy instances? I've tried to search It alot, but unfortunately, I could not find It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, one azcopy instance only supports one source and one destination.

So if you want to copy to 2 destinations, you must use 2 azcopy commands, and each command is responsible for copying to one destination.